# Actual wait time for interview on immediate relative sponsorship

Tags: us-citizens, greencard, application-status

My wife (US Citizen) applied for my permanent residence (change of status) on July 13, 2015. We submitted i-130 and i-485 to the USCIS at the same time. I had my biometrics fingerprint taken 2 months later. But since then USCIS has been reporting `Case Is Ready To Be Scheduled For An Interview` and its already been 7 months now.

Can someone please give me a hint on when should I expect to be called for an interview? I think the visa bulletin does not apply to me because my wife and I are both in the United States and me being an immediate relative (of my wife's) don't have to wait for a visa to be available.

Comment: Have you tried to get an answer from USCIS?

Comment: Are you saying that I can call them and find out when I am going to have an interview? I am checking case.uscis.gov every single day expecting that they will update it as soon as they find out.

Comment: I don't know if you can call them, but if I were you I'd look for a number and call it. Even if they don't know when they will interview, they will either be able to estimate how long you can expect to wait for an appointment to be scheduled, or that they are unable to give you an estimate.

Comment: You can most definitely call them (1-800-375-5283), and also walk in to the local USCIS office for an infopass appointment (https://infopass.uscis.gov/).

Comment: @summerNight Let us know when you received this, this would help in knowing the time period. Also what office have you filed this with? Thanks

Comment: @pal4life: I talked to my lawyers and they said it will be processed through the National Benefits Center. Once the NBC has completed review of all documents, and all security clearance checks are done, they will transfer the case to the Field Office in my city for an interview

Comment: @summerNight So you mean you have not received yet, wow that means it is taking quite some time.

Comment: @pal4life Exactly, I filed on July 13, 2015 and have been waiting for the interview

Comment: @summerNight I would definitely recommend connecting with USCIS to find out more on whats going on with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It varies for everybody. It can take as long as a year (or in rare cases more) for some people in some cases.

Did you check the [USCIS processing times](https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processTimesDisplayInit.do) for your local office? (Select your local office under "Field Office" and look at the processing time for I-485. Remember that the times are not constantly updated so the date you see is the filing dates they were processing at the time the processing times were last reported.) Is your application beyond the timeframe for the office? Even if it is beyond the timeframe for that office, your particular case could be slower than the average because they are doing extra security checks or something.

If your case becomes really behind, you can contact your congressman or senator and/or the [CIS Ombudsman](https://www.dhs.gov/topic/cis-ombudsman) to see if they can help move it along. But if it's within normal processing times, they're not likely going to do anything.

Hopefully, you applied for an EAD (with I-765) and Advance Parole (with I-131) with your Adjustment of Status application. They are free to apply for and with them you can work and travel and has most of the benefits of permanent residency, so it doesn't matter as much how long it takes for your AOS to be approved. If you haven't applied for them yet, you can still apply for them for free; but it takes about 90 days from applying to get them.

Comment: @user102008: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. I do have `an EAD (with I-765) and Advance Parole (with I-131)`. So does this mean I can travel anywhere and can return back to the US before the card expires without any hassles at all? Will they ask for any specific documents when I return back to the US?

Comment: @summerNight: That's right. Just the AP and a passport, and maybe the I-485 receipt just in case.